# React: why not mutate this.state directly in componentWillReceiveProps? or call setState in the constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating components by reading in an XML file. Every tag in the XML file (e.g. `<video src="intro.mp4" />`) will be parsed and mapped to its same named component `Video`. This is the case for all XML tags.

Because of this: certain components are reused and will get completely different props than before, because they are getting attributes from a completely different tag.

For example, there is a `<video ... />` tag at line 1 which maps to the `Video` component which plays a video. Then at some point the video is stopped. In some cases, before React unmounts the component, the new `<video ... />` tag is already read in, say for example at line 15.

Because of this I am now forced to reset this component via `componentWillReceiveProps` and because of this, the code that is in here looks a lot like the code that the constructor also has.

The difference between constructor code and `componentWillReceiveProps` code is that in the constructor, the state is mutated directly and in `componentWillReceiveProps` it isn't. My issue is that I'd like to abstract this code away in a function which I'd like to call both in the constructor and in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

So my question is: could I better call `setState(...)` in the constructor or mutate state directly in `componentWillReceiveProps`?

Currently I have stuff like the following all over the place, dupclicated:

```
//in the constructor
this.state = {
  key: shortid.generate(),
  localMediaItems: this.props.playlist.children.filter( element => {
    if(element.attributes && //.attributes property must exist
      element.attributes.stopAtSubjectId !== undefined){
      pubSub.publish('addGlobalMediaItem', element); //publish to Playlist
      this.state = {
        stopCounter: this.state.stopCounter + 1
      }
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }) 
}


componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
//new XML tag has been read in, reset state as it were a new component mounting
  if(propsCompare(this.props, nextProps) === false){
    this.setState({
      key: shortid.generate(),
      localMediaItems: nextProps.playlist.children.filter( element => {
        if(element.attributes && //.attributes property must exist
          element.attributes.stopAtSubjectId !== undefined){
            pubSub.publish('addGlobalMediaItem', element); //publish to Playlist
            return false;
        }
        return true;
      })
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: why have internal state at all? if the state is coming from props, just use the props directly. furthermore, you can't call setState in constructor.. that's just where you define the initial state. if you want to update state anywhere else you have to call setState

Comment: You do not mutate your state in the constructor, you set the initial state, because there is no state at this point. Second calls to `setState()` can be batched by react into a single update to prevent unnecessary re-renders. A direct mutation of the state will not trigger a re-render. It makes absolutely no sense to abstract this because the is nothing to abstract at all.

Comment: But in componentWillReceiveProps you will not trigger a rerender anyway.

Comment: [You can of course call `setState()` in `componentWillReceiveProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) which will trigger a re-render. But it will not, when you mutate the state directly. There is no reason to mutate the state directly and as @azium already said you don't even need the state as it is always fully derivable from the props. It does only change when the props change and only contains information that is already in the props. So it is basically useless except of the counter.